# Windows 10: как исключить язык из переключения по Alt-Shift?

Tags: windows, windows-10, клавиатура, смена-языка

У меня на Window 10 стоят два языка: русский и английский. Соответсвенно есть две раскладки клавиатуры. Я активно пользуюсь обеими. Сейчас я изучаю ещё один иностранный язык и для работы с ним мне нужна третья раскладка. Если добавить этот язык в Windows, то он появляется в списке языков ввода переключаемых по Alt-Shift. Но мне ввод на этом языке нужен время от времени, а не на постоянной основе. А по Alt-Shift он мешает тем, что периодически приходится нажимать Alt-Shift два раза, чтобы перейти с русского на английский, пропуская этот язык.

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли способ исключить часть языков ввода установленных в системе из круга переключаемых по Alt-Shift языков?

Мне **не** нужно изменять сочетание клавиш для переключения языков. Alt-Shift меня устравивает. Мне нужно, чтобы при устаноленных в системе трёх языках, например английском, русском и китайском переключение по нажатию Alt-Shift происходило так:

Английский - Русский - Английский - Русский ....

а не так:

Английский - Русский - Китайский - Английский - Русский - Китайский - ...

При этом китайский должен быть доступен среди языков ввода. Его можно будет выбрать либо мышкой через языковую панель, либо отдельным сочетанием клавишь. Например Ctrl-1.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не по теме данного ресурса.

Comment: @0xdb, это вполне вопрос по системному администрированию, т.е. по теме данного ресурса. К сожалению, нет русскоязычного аналога https://superuser.com/

Comment: Здесь https://superuser.com/a/1368543/1106749 вроде бы то, что вам нужно

Comment: На superuser.com/a/1368543/1106749 опять же как поменять сочетание клавиш, а не как поменять список языков ввода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашёл точно такой же вопрос на [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1263219/exclude-an-input-language-from-altshift-switching-cycle-on-windows-10). Там предложено два решения. Для обоих решений нужно установить [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), скопировать на диск скрипт для него и запускать этот скрипт через автозапуск. Для автозапуска его можно например скопировать в папку `C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. Для проверки работы этот скрипт можно запустить вручную, двойным щелчком по нему.

**Первое решение.**
В Windows 10 оказывается есть клавиатурная комбинация, которая переключает раскладку на предыдущую: Win-Ctrl-Пробел. В этом скрипте нажатие на Alt-Shift преобразуется в нажатие Win-Ctrl-Пробел. Сам скрипт:

```
; This scripts changes the functionality of Shift + Alt from "switch keyboard layout"
; to "change to previous layout".
; this is usefull when you have more than 2 keyboard layouts and want to switch between 
; only 2 of them.

#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

LAlt & LShift::send, #^{space down}{space up}
```

Это решение я проверил - оно работает. Но нужно помнить, что оно переключает на предыдущий язык. То есть, если у вас был включен китайский, то этот скрипт будет переключать на китайский, так как он был предыдущим. Поэтому надо будет вручную, мышкой через языковую панель по очереди выбрать два языка, между которыми нужно переключатся и после этого можно будет снова нормально работать.

**Второе решение.**
Во втором решении скрипт непосредсвенно включает нужный язык ввода при нажатии Alt-Shift. Но его нужно настроить перед использованием: задать нужные коды языков. Для этого их надо где-то узнать. В приведенном здесь варианте скрипта основные языки русский и английский, дополнительный язык: японский.

```
#SingleInstance force
SendMode Input

; Cycled list of language ids
; refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/language-identifiers
; and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/language-identifier-constants-and-strings
; for finding out correct values
; in this case 0x409 means standard US English, and 0x419 means standard Russian
AltShiftLangs := [0x0409, 0x0419]

; 0x411 means japanese IME
CtrlAltLang := 0x0411

; This returns currently active language id
GetKeyboardLayout() {
  WinGet, WinID,, A
  ThreadID:=DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "UInt", WinID, "UInt", 0)
  return DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "UInt", ThreadID, "UInt") & 0xFFFF
}

; This sends request to change system language to lang argument
SetKeyboardLayout(lang) {
  PostMessage, 0x50,, lang,, A
}

; This returns 0-based index of Value in Arr
IndexOf(Arr, Value) {
  Loop % Arr.Length()
    if Arr[A_Index] == Value {
      return A_Index-1
    }
  return -1
}

; This sets language based on current system lanuage and next value by index in Arr
; If current language is not found, it sets system to first language from Arr
SetNextLanguage(Arr) {
  lang := GetKeyboardLayout()
  idx := IndexOf(Arr, lang)
  if (idx < 0) {
    SetKeyboardLayout(Arr[1])
    return
  }
  nextIdx := mod(idx+1, Arr.Length())
  next := Arr[nextIdx+1]
  SetKeyboardLayout(next)
}

; Alt+Shift hotkey - cycle between AltShiftLangs
LAlt & LShift::
SetNextLanguage(AltShiftLangs)
return

; Ctrl+Alt hotkey - switch directly to isolated CtrlAltLang
LCtrl & LAlt::
SetKeyboardLayout(CtrlAltLang)
return
```

Это решение я не проверял.